# Choose the top five values from each group in r

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I'm working on `hflights` dataset in R trying to extract some useful insights. I managed to get the most visited destinations in weekends for each season. As I want to make a plot for my insight, I want to get only the top 5 destinations for each season.

I tried this code below but I did not get the top 5 destinations for each season. Can any one help with this issue? What is the best way to deal with variable after summarising it (flights in our case)?

```
allseasons <- hflights %>%
  filter(DayOfWeek == c(6, 7)) %>%
  mutate(Season = case_when(
    Month %in% 3:5 ~ "Spring",
    Month %in% 9:11 ~ "Autumn", 
    Month %in% 6:8 ~ "Summer", 
    Month %in% 12:2 ~ "Winter")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Season)) %>%
  group_by(Dest, Season) %>%
  summarise(flights = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(flights)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Season)) %>%
  top_n(5, flights)
```

The Result:

```
Dest  Season flights
   <chr> <chr>    <int>
 1 DAL   Winter     166
 2 DFW   Winter     149
 3 ATL   Winter     146
 4 DEN   Winter     133
 5 MSY   Winter     124
 6 ORD   Winter     118
 7 LAX   Winter     114
 8 PHX   Winter     107
 9 EWR   Winter     102
10 CLT   Winter      92
# ... with 428 more rows
```

Comment: since you have sorted your data you could use `slice(1:5)`

Comment: By `filter(DayOfWeek == c(6, 7))` you almost certainly mean `filter(DayOfWeek %in% c(6, 7))`

Comment: since you want to maintain the season grouping after you summarise, you should also change the order to `group_by(Season,Dest)`

Comment: Concur with @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an alternative to the answers already provided in case you want to use `top_n` specifically - you may want to due to the way it handles ties.

```
 hflights %>%
  filter(DayOfWeek %in% c(6, 7)) %>%
  mutate(Season = case_when(
    Month %in% 3:5 ~ "Spring",
    Month %in% 9:11 ~ "Autumn", 
    Month %in% 6:8 ~ "Summer", 
    Month %in% c(12, 1, 2) ~ "Winter")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Season)) %>%
  group_by(Season, Dest) %>%
  summarise(flights = n()) %>%
  top_n(5, flights) %>%
  arrange(Season, desc(flights))
```

Your main issue was with `group_by(Dest,Season)` as I pointed out in the comments. `summarise()` removes the last layer of grouping so was leaving your data grouped by Dest and not Season.

Your sorting with `arrange()` was redundant and should be done after using `top_n`.

As others have pointed out you should also be using `%in%` when comparing a value to more than one value rather than `==`.

Comment: @Rami_Kh about your plot - you need to think about the best way to visualise this. Perhaps a bar plot of destination Vs flights, faceted by season.

Comment: @Ozan147 point taken about there being no NAs in the relevant columns, thanks. `group_by` does arrange by Season but the sorting is necessary to get the flights in the correct order as `top_n` does not do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

here is similar example based on iris (which gives top 5 of some calculated stat for a defined groups) :

```
  iris%>%
  select(Species, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)%>%
  group_by(Species, Petal.Length)%>%
  summarise(s=sum(Petal.Width))%>%
  arrange(Species, -s)%>%
  top_n(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chris and @alistaire already pointed out some important steps in their comments. Additionally, assuming days of the week starts with Sunday (not sure though, you can tweak that part):

- `Month %in% c(12, 1, 2)` instead of `Month %in% 12:2`

**Following up your comment:**

You will get 7 destinations as you have 7 unique destinations. Please try to change your visualization method to achieve what you want. Faceting may be of help as given below:

```
library(hflights)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

allseasons <- hflights %>%
  filter(DayOfWeek %in% 6:7) %>%
  mutate(
    Season = case_when(
      Month %in% 3:5 ~ "Spring",
      Month %in% 9:11 ~ "Autumn", 
      Month %in% 6:8 ~ "Summer", 
      Month %in% c(12, 1, 2) ~ "Winter"
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(Season, Dest) %>%
  summarise(flights = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(flights)) %>%
  slice(1:5)

ggplot(allseasons, aes(x = Dest, y = flights, fill = Season)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplot(allseasons, aes(x = Dest, y = flights)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Season)
```

Comment: Why `slice(c(1,2,3,4,5))` ? Why not `1:5`

Comment: I don't know why I made it weird :) Thank you for pointing out! Just refactored it along with others.

Comment: no worries just saves on typing. +1 anyway.  BTW the day of the week does start on Monday - you can tell by looking up some of the dates.

Comment: @Ozan147 Thank you mates! This works so good for me. But I was wondering about the way to plot a graph for top 5 for each season. I tried: ggplot(allseasons, aes(x = Dest, y = flights, fill = Season)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") but I got a plot for 7 destinations.

Comment: @Chris his works so good for me. But I was wondering about the way to plot a graph for top 5 for each season. I tried: ggplot(allseasons, aes(x = Dest, y = flights, fill = Season)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") but I got a plot for 7 destinations.

Comment: @Rami_Kh, it is normal as you have 7 unique destinations, just updated my answer. Please try another visualization method.

Comment: @Ozan147 Thank you dear Ozan. Actually I tried the same code for plot but the point is that I want to get the same structure of the dataframe in my plot: I mean, I want only to get 5 bars (most visited destinations) for each season. Do have any suggestion?